# Regex returns only the first match

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have this string:

```
1 = 0 AND 2 = 3
```

and am using this regular expression:

```
\s*(?<SearchCondition>.+?)\s*(AND|OR|$)
```

I would like to return the following as showing in (http://regexhero.net/tester/) but it doesn't for some reason:

```
1: AND
SearchCondition: 1 = 0
1: 
SearchCondition: 2 = 3
```

Here is my code:

```
  Dim whereElem As String = "1 = 0 AND 2 = 3"
  Dim regex As New Regex("\s*(?<SearchCondition>.+?)\s*(AND|OR|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  m = regex.Match(whereElem)

  If m.Success Then
       Console.WriteLine(m.Groups("SearchCondition").Captures.Count)
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT: 2**

I am doing something wrong here but just don't see it. Any tips where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why tag C# if this is VB.Net code?

Comment: I think it wouldn't matter. They can read it easily. More people use C#.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I want this to print 2

Comment: @Denis The point of tags is not to gain visibility. They're supposed to represent the content of the question. I've removed the C# tag

Comment: you mean the 2 before `= 3`?

Comment: your RegexHero link doesn't link us to your test

Comment: what is your desired output, can you update your question with it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: That's fine. It's not the problem. I am trying to count how many times the group "SearchCondition" would appear

Comment: @RGraham, I agree with your change - I just didn't think my question really related to c# or vb.net. I just put together vb.net because that is what I was looking at, could have written the code in C#. Wouldn't really have changed the essence of the question as it is something to do with the regular expression which would be the same problem whether you are using vb.net or c#.

Comment: @Jonesy - that site doesn't save the text or the regular expression. You can take it from this post and paste to regexhero.

Comment: @Denis Then the correct way to tag it is *neither* C# nor VB. Just tag it `[regex]`, and even `[.net]`. 10.1k followers and a lot of experts

Comment: @RGraham - you are right! But it did turn out to be a c#/VB.NET issue and not a regex issue.

Comment: C# and VB.NET are languages. .NET is the framework. The framework was the issue, not the language. You could've argued this applied to C++.NET too, but again....the language is not at fault here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex only matches a single expression, followed by a `AND`, `OR`, or the end of the string:

```regex
\s*                      # whitespace
(?<SearchCondition>.+?)  # match and capture before the whitespace
\s*                      # more whitespace 
(AND|OR|$)               # either AND, OR, or end of line
```

Since your input is `1 = 0 AND 2 = 3`, calling `Regex.Match` will stop after the first `AND`.

You probably want to use `Regex.Matches` instead to find all the matches:

```cs
var matches = regex.Matches(whereElem);
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["SearchCondition"]);
```

Hope you don't mind the answer in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a regex for this simple thing, when the `String` class provides an easy way.
Use of regex is not recommended if things are not too complex, due to the processing overheads they have.

Here is a one-liner solution for you:

```
Dim searchConditions() As String = whereElem.Split(New String() {" AND ", " OR "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Sometimes you get fixated on doing things one way and don't see the simple ways. But I guess they could put newlines around the ANDs and ORs. That is the only thing I can think of but I guess I could fix that with Trim(...). Interesting idea.

Comment: Line breaks should not be a problem. Just replace them with space before splitting the string.